# How can I persist React-native redux state using redux-persist?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I've been trying to use redux-perist to save my redux-state to `AsyncStorage`. Although I keep getting an error:

```
_this.store.getState is not a function
```

I'm not sure why this is happening?

Here is my setup:

#### configureStore.js:

```
import {AsyncStorage,} from 'react-native';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers, } from 'redux';
import reduxThunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import Reactotron from 'reactotron';
import * as reducers from './modules';
import devTools from 'remote-redux-devtools';
import {persistStore, autoRehydrate} from 'redux-persist'


Reactotron.connect({
  enabled: __DEV__,
});

const enhancer = compose(
  autoRehydrate(),
  applyMiddleware(
    reduxThunkMiddleware,
    Reactotron.reduxMiddleware,
  ),
  devTools()
);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      ...reducers,
    }),
    initialState,
    enhancer,
  );
  Reactotron.addReduxStore(store, {storage: AsyncStorage});
  return store;
}
```

#### App.js:

Here is where I connect my `store`, to my `<provider>`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Router } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import routes from '@routes/app';
import createStore from './redux/create'; // Returns store object from the above configureStore.js!
import {persistStore} from 'redux-persist'
const RouterWithRedux = connect()(Router);

const store = persistStore(createStore(), {storage: AsyncStorage}); // Not working??
const Kernel = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <RouterWithRedux scenes={routes} />
  </Provider>
);

export default Kernel;
```

Comment: persistStorage takes a callback which is triggered when it's done, I'm not sure, but perhaps that might be the problem. Here is a working example: http://pastebin.com/EKXeiYyg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const RouterWithRedux = connect()(Router);
const store = createStore();
const persistor = persistStore(store, {storage: AsyncStorage}); // Not working??
const Kernel = () => (
  <Provider store={store} persistor={persistor}>
    <RouterWithRedux scenes={routes} />
  </Provider>
);
```

The problem was I had to pass down a persistor field as well as the store field.

After adding in the persistor field, my store was being persisted into AsyncStorage

#### EDIT:

This worked at the time - It has occured to me that this not the *correct* solution to the problem. But I'm still getting responses that it still works, if someone could provide another answer for everyone else, that'd be great.

Comment: why is this not a recommended way for react-native in redux-persist docs? I was getting "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined" error, this ans fixed the problem. thanks!

Comment: I'm actually not sure @Preetam but it did fix it for me

Comment: How does this fix the problem? I don't even see a property persistor on the Provider component. 

https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/Provider.js

Comment: Wow, it works, but why persistor props on Provider when it is not a property on Provider component?

Comment: `Provider.propTypes = {
        store: storeShape.isRequired,
        children: PropTypes.element.isRequired
}`

Comment: Do you have a "correct" solution to the problem as you mentioned?